# Basic tutorials for developing simple Facebook application in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I need to develop a Facebook application. I have generated the application ID and secret Key. I am in search of some good tutorials and I got some code 
from [this url](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/stride-android/team/stride/tabs/settings/SettingsActivity.java.htm), but it needs some packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.  You should use official Facebook SDK for Android

http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/

Comment: Hi, can u please suggest me tutorials