# Integrating Facebook with Android app

Tags: android, facebook

I want to integrate facebook with my android app, so that I can share stuff from my app on facebook. I want to use the official facebook-sdk for android.
Now I have created a dummy app on facebook and generated my API key for that.
But after that I am stuck . Where can I find some example code for this.
I don't know what methods or what format I have to use in my code.

Please tell me how to achieve this and where can I find some example code for the same.

Comment: What is that do you want to share ?, is your app java based?

Comment: you see this link [integration of facebook with android](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/)

Comment: Check these solutions: [solution1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372020/facebook-integration-in-android-application) [solution2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323496/looking-for-android-facebook-sdk-examples) [solution3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577921/facebook-fbrocket-api-for-android) [solution4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122721/basic-tutorials-for-developing-simple-facebook-application-in-android)